# PyAudio install error after updated to Xcode 12

Tags: python, python-3.x, xcode, macos, pyaudio

I have been updated to Xcode 12, but when I trying to install PyAudio, I always got an error like this:
(I also tried to install with sudo, with and without venv, which got same error like this...)

- OS: macOS 10.15.6 (19G2021)
- Python: 3.8
- Xcode version: 12

```
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pyaudio, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
    Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/userid/Desktop/Workspace/Projects/hello-world/env/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/dg/ppgz73fs3ml5zs4mxqtw_z_c0000gn/T/pip-install-qfayqnx7/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/dg/ppgz73fs3ml5zs4mxqtw_z_c0000gn/T/pip-install-qfayqnx7/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/dg/ppgz73fs3ml5zs4mxqtw_z_c0000gn/T/pip-record-8ls2_tdo/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/userid/Desktop/Workspace/Projects/hello-world/env/include/site/python3.8/pyaudio
         cwd: /private/var/folders/dg/ppgz73fs3ml5zs4mxqtw_z_c0000gn/T/pip-install-qfayqnx7/pyaudio/
    Complete output (104 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8
    copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/src
    xcrun -sdk macosx clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -DMACOSX=1 -I/Users/userid/Desktop/Workspace/Projects/hello-world/env/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/src/_portaudiomodule.o
    In file included from src/_portaudiomodule.c:27:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:68:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:807:2: error: Unsupported architecture
    #error Unsupported architecture
     ^
    In file included from src/_portaudiomodule.c:27:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:33:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: architecture not supported
    #error architecture not supported
     ^
    In file included from src/_portaudiomodule.c:27:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
    typedef __int64_t       __darwin_blkcnt_t;      /* total blocks */
            ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:56:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
    typedef __int32_t       __darwin_blksize_t;     /* preferred block size */
            ^
    note: '__int128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:57:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
    typedef __int32_t       __darwin_dev_t;         /* dev_t */
            ^
    note: '__int128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:60:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_gid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:61:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_id_t;          /* [XSI] pid_t, uid_t, or gid_t*/
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:62:9: error: unknown type name '__uint64_t'
    typedef __uint64_t      __darwin_ino64_t;       /* [???] Used for 64 bit inodes */
            ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:68:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_natural_t'
    typedef __darwin_natural_t __darwin_mach_port_name_t; /* Used by mach */
            ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:70:9: error: unknown type name '__uint16_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint16_t      __darwin_mode_t;        /* [???] Some file attributes */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:71:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
    typedef __int64_t       __darwin_off_t;         /* [???] Used for file sizes */
            ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:72:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
    typedef __int32_t       __darwin_pid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
            ^
    note: '__int128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:73:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_sigset_t;      /* [???] signal set */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:74:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
    typedef __int32_t       __darwin_suseconds_t;   /* [???] microseconds */
            ^
    note: '__int128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:75:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_uid_t;         /* [???] user IDs */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:76:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_useconds_t;    /* [???] microseconds */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    In file included from src/_portaudiomodule.c:27:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:43:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_wctype_t;
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    In file included from src/_portaudiomodule.c:27:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:75:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_va_list.h:31:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/machine/types.h:37:2: error: architecture not supported
    #error architecture not supported
     ^
    In file included from src/_portaudiomodule.c:27:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:75:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_va_list.h:32:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_va_list'
    typedef __darwin_va_list va_list;
            ^
    fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
    20 errors generated.
    error: command 'xcrun' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/userid/Desktop/Workspace/Projects/hello-world/env/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/dg/ppgz73fs3ml5zs4mxqtw_z_c0000gn/T/pip-install-qfayqnx7/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/dg/ppgz73fs3ml5zs4mxqtw_z_c0000gn/T/pip-install-qfayqnx7/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/dg/ppgz73fs3ml5zs4mxqtw_z_c0000gn/T/pip-record-8ls2_tdo/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/userid/Desktop/Workspace/Projects/hello-world/env/include/site/python3.8/pyaudio Check the logs for full command output.
```

Anyone can help? thanks!

Answer (score 15):

I was able to work around this by exporting an environment variable

`export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"`

Comment: Thanks for adding this I was stuck on this for so long. I have tried and its working absolutely fine.

Comment: Thanks! Been struggling with this all day